# How do I go around this error am getting while trying to run a file on streamlit using streamlit run

Tags: streamlit

This is what I am getting:

**C:\Users\Imai040>streamlit run "C:/Users/Imai040/PycharmProjects/stock prediction/main.py"
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\programdata\anaconda3\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Imai040\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts\streamlit.exe" run "C:/Users/Imai040/PycharmProjects/stock prediction/main.py"': The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: Yes I have the file

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using Windows OS, you may try the steps below:**

1. First, you need to download Anaconda: https://www.anaconda.com/
2. Open the Anaconda PowerShell Prompt and type the following:

   `conda list`

   `pip uninstall streamlit`
3. Create a new environment, and test out the following:

   `pip install streamlit`

   `streamlit hello`
4. Finally, you can test out streamlit on your code, replace *your_app* with the actual name of your file. Make sure you are in the same directory as your source code file.

   `streamlit run your_app.py`